# average (mean) 2 columns of dataframe in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to average 2 columns (income and expenditure) based on their name in col A as below (to find an average yearly value for each). I think I'm getting a syntax error but not exactly sure where I'm going wrong and I've tried a few different variations but no luck.

This is my snippet of my table;

```
GroupName   Year    Age Size    Income  Expenditure
yellow      2008    35  2.7     46704   42394
red         2008    29  2.6     23404   25270
yellow      2010    40  2.3     16747   21145
red         2012    34  2.8     31308   29855
blue        2008    31  3.0     49106   46561
green       2008    35  2.6     61674   52776
```

this is my code;

```
NewGroupfactsDS <- NewGroupfactsDS %>%
group_by(GroupName) %>% summarize(AvgExpenditure = mean(Expenditure), summarize(AvgIncome = mean(Income))
```

Thanks for any help in advance :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just remove the second `summarize`. And consider also Rui Barradas suggestions with `across`

```
NewGroupfactsDS <- NewGroupfactsDS %>%
  group_by(GroupName) %>% 
  summarize(AvgExpenditure = mean(Expenditure), AvgIncome = mean(Income))
```

Output:

```
  GroupName AvgExpenditure AvgIncome
  <chr>              <dbl>     <dbl>
1 blue              46561     49106 
2 green             52776     61674 
3 red               27562.    27356 
4 yellow            31770.    31726.
```

Answer (score 5):

Here are two ways, the first with `across` and the second correcting the error in the question's code.

```
library(dplyr)

NewGroupfactsDS <- NewGroupfactsDS %>%
  group_by(GroupName) %>% 
  summarize(across(c(Expenditure, Income), mean))

NewGroupfactsDS <- NewGroupfactsDS %>%
  group_by(GroupName) %>% 
  summarize(AvgExpenditure = mean(Expenditure),
            AvgIncome = mean(Income))
```

Answer (score 0):

Base R answer

```
aggregate(DF[,4:5], list("GroupName" = DF$GroupName), mean)
```